# Network usage of a process in linux

Tags: linux, network-monitoring

I would like to record the total number of bytes transferred over the network by different versions of VNC.  My plan is to start the VNC viewer, run a script remotely that performs some actions and displays some graphics and then disconnects.

How can you record the total network usage of just this one process in linux? I don't want to measure anything else that is happening on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the different versions of the VNC viewers on different port numbers and then record all traffic to those ports with a tool such as tcpdump.

There may be some way of recording traffic per process but doing it by port is much more obvious and simple

crude example using perl to add up/filter

```
sudo tcpdump -li eth1 ' port 5900'|perl -ne 'print $c,"\n"; $c+=$1 if (/length (\d+)/);'
```

Comment: Something like 'tcpdump -i eth1 'port 1080'' and then convert the output to bytes somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You should try **`iftop`** Linux command.

```
$ sudo iftop -i eth0 -P
server.example.com:ssh     => client.example.com:51365         1.73kb  2.72kb  2.72kb
```

More elegant way using filters:

```
$sudo iftop -i eth0 -f "dst port 22"
```

Comment: Very interesting application. Thank you.  Can it be made to save the total data usage?

Comment: `iftop` does not have such an option but `iptraf` can log into file.